# How do I use an Access SQL query to track inventory composition?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Suppose I have a list of inventory I have acquired/discarded:

```
Date       Quantity    Item
1/1/2000      10      Apple
2/2/2000       5      Orange
21/10/2000     1      Banana
4/1/2001       2      Apple
8/8/2000      -3      Orange
```

I would now like to generate a query that can produce the number of oranges, bananas and apples I have at every time point:

```
Date       Quantity    Item
1/1/2000      10      Apple
2/2/2000       5      Orange
21/10/2000     1      Banana
4/1/2001      12      Apple
8/8/2000       2      Orange
```

Is something like this possible in Access? I'm stumped and don't really know where to start on this.

Comment: what should be the query result?
do you want a simple sum of qty  based on item type?

Comment: @HosseinSalmanian yeah that sounds right. Please note I've changed the desired output, I just realised that what I had before wasn't really what I was after.

Comment: it seems you want keep tracking of change of quantity with change of Date , is it true?

Comment: @HosseinSalmanian Yes, that's correct.

Comment: The quantity field is actually "change_in_qty" so to speak, is that right? And what you want is a "total_qty" output column, indicating the sum of the current row's change, and all previous rows' changes for that item?

Comment: @BrianDeMilia Yes that's exactly right, you phrased it much better than I did!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select curr.[Date],
       curr.[Quantity] as change_in_qty,
       sum(prev.[Quantity])+curr.[Quantity] as total_qty,
       curr.[Item]
  from tblname curr
 inner join tblname prev
    on curr.[Item] = prev.[Item]
 where prev.[Date] < curr.[Date]
 group by curr.[Date],
          curr.[Quantity],
          curr.[Item]
union all
select [Date],
       [Quantity],
       [Quantity],
       [Item]
  from tblname x
 where not exists ( select 1
                    from tblname y
                    where y.[Item] = x.[Item]
                      and y.[Date] < x.[Date] ) z
```

Should sum up all rows for the given item where the date is less than that of the date on the current row.

Comment: That won't print the quantity of items that have not changed though. In my example, it wouldn't print the first 3 rows.

Comment: @Arman I just edited the sql so that it connects w/ another query that picks up any items that don't have 2+ rows on the table.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to see quantity
of item by date you may want to try this statement using a `Group BY`.

```
Select [Date],Count(*) As Quantity,
 Item from Inventory group by Date,Item
```

Answer (score 1):

with lack of  cursor in access database
Like the t-sql that you can write in sql server 
you can't force the database  to do it for you
so you must fetch data from db and do the procedure in your code

Comment: You can do this an access, it is just more difficult because access does not have analytic functions. If you were using sql server / oracle / postgresql he could easily use sum(quantity) over(partition by item order by item, dt)