# How do I create a table that displays Current Inventory based on the location of said Inventory using Pl/SQL?

Tags: plsql

Here is what I have:

```
product    location    quantity     moved     dttm

apple      shop1       30           null      '08/10/22' 
orange     shop1       20           null      '08/15/22' 
pear       shop1       40           null      '08/20/22' 
apple      shop2       10           shop1     '08/22/22' 
orange     shop3       15           shop1     '08/22/22'
```

Where Location is the current location of product, with that quantity, and moved is the previous location of the inventory (which is sometimes null if it is being added to the system), and dttm the date that change occurred.

I'm looking for a way to show the current inventory based changes made to the data set. The view Should look something like the below:

```
Location    Product    Quantity 

shop1      apple       20 
shop1      orange      5 
shop1      pear        40
shop2      apple       10
shop3      orange      15
```

What is the best practice for making a view this way? I have yet to come up with a working query that gives accurate numbers. I have the side that adds inventory to a location working (using an `outer apply` statement. I'm getting hung up on how to get my `move` column to substract inventory from products at a given location.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24971036/how-do-i-use-an-access-sql-query-to-track-inventory-composition?newreg=81cd4dcaf8b5417887a8743de62dfe35) seems to be close to what I want, but with the added complexity of location also being a factor in the totals for the items.

What am I missing? or does my dataset need to be remade to accomplish what I want?

Thanks for any and all help

Comment: PL/SQL is the programming language. It sounds like you need a SQL query.

Comment: Also tables and views are two different things. It sounds like you need a view.

Comment: @williamrobertson Yes you're correct on both counts. Self taught problems ha. This is all designed to work in the back end for use in an Apex application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one option: create a view (or a subquery, or use a CTE - as I did) as union of **locations** (either as the original locations, or *moved* ones), and the rest is then easy - a simple aggregation.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (product, location, quantity, moved) as
  2    (select 'apple'  , 'shop1', 30, null    from dual union all
  3     select 'orange' , 'shop1', 20, null    from dual union all
  4     select 'pear'   , 'shop1', 40, null    from dual union all
  5     select 'apple'  , 'shop2', 10, 'shop1' from dual union all
  6     select 'orange' , 'shop3', 15, 'shop1' from dual
  7    ),
```

Query begins here:

```
  8  temp as
  9    (select location, product,  quantity from test
 10     union all
 11     select moved   , product, -quantity from test where moved is not null
 12    )
 13  select location, product, sum(quantity) quantity
 14  from temp
 15  group by location, product
 16  order by location, product
 17  /

LOCAT PRODUC   QUANTITY
----- ------ ----------
shop1 apple          20
shop1 orange          5
shop1 pear           40
shop2 apple          10
shop3 orange         15

SQL>
```

Comment: Nice. This is working. I replaced temp with a direct query { where (select)} to get it working in my environment (Apex) and added some nvl fixing for user input error on the quantity field. Was even able to use this a base to get another view for number of distinct items in a given store. Much appreciated!